# Hbase rowkey with space

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

Can a rowkey have a space and some special characters like & ?

Example - USA.new York.383937.abc@.1000

Is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can have these characters and/or space.
If omitting them(for example SPACE) does not cause key conflict, then it would be better to not have them in case having or not having them makes difference of a new block.

**KeyValue instances are not split across blocks. For example, if there is an 8 MB KeyValue, even if the block-size is 64kb this KeyValue will be read in as a coherent block.**

But, it should worry you only if KeyValues are having block additions too frequently because of this which is not very common, so it should not be a concern.

[reference document](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.3.8/book/regions.arch.html#keyvalue)